# In react-native-maps, reverse y axis in UrlTile (for support of TMS)

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

React-native-maps supports custom tile overlays with UrlTile component. They are using Google maps and OSM style tile numbering, where 0, 0 is upper left corner.

Is there possibility to use TMS tiles, where 0, 0 refers to lower left corner (y-axis is reversed)?

I got no other idea than writing server-side proxy, which would parse x,y,z out from URL, reverse y and curl tile from Tile server with correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with patching AirMapUrlTile.java, I added new substitution for variable 'yr' (standing for y reversed).

```
String s = this.urlTemplate
    .replace("{x}", Integer.toString(x))
    .replace("{y}", Integer.toString(y))
    .replace("{yr}", Integer.toString((1<<zoom) - y - 1))
    .replace("{z}", Integer.toString(zoom));
```

This allows usage of urlTemplates like `http://my.tms.server.com/layer/{z}/{x}/{yr}.png`

But it would be nice to have some official solution for that, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `<UrlTile urlTemplate="..." flipY={true}`.